# How is void invalid type for method addContact(String name, Integer number) and removeContact(String name)?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap, set

I am getting the invalid type error in both the methods.what could be the valid type for my both methods.

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> contacts = new HashMap<>();

public void addContact(String name, Integer number) {
    contacts.put(name, number);
}

public void removeContact(String name) {
    contacts.remove(name);
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@shubham Please make sure the snippet of code you pasted here is not written inside the main() method. If you define your code snippet inside a class, it will not have any compilation issue.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Test1
{

    HashMap<String, Integer> contacts = new HashMap<>();

    public void addContact(String name, Integer number) {
        contacts.put(name, number);
    }

    public void removeContact(String name) {
        contacts.remove(name);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```